# Why am I not getting error when I store values of different types in an array in C language?

Tags: c, arrays

This is the code:

```
    int a[3]={3,5,'s'};
    printf("%d%c",a[1],a[2]);
```

I compile it with gcc like this

```
    gcc test.c -o test
```

and it is working without a problem, output:

```
    5s
```

I thought I should get an error because I have a character in an integer array.
What is happening here?

Comment: `'s'` that is a `char` gets automatically casted to an `int`.

Comment: @dms No. It _is_ of type `int`

Comment: Ah! Learnt something new, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, character literals are of type `int` See [C11 Character constants](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4) which says "¶2 An integer character constant is a sequence of one or more multibyte characters enclosed in single-quotes, … — ¶10: An integer character constant has type `int`." Consequently, doing

```
 int a[3]={3,5,'s'};
```

won't be a problem. The actual stored value is typically 115 which is the ASCII equivalent of 's'

```
 printf("%d%c",a[1],a[2]);
```

`%c` would print the character corresponding to 115.

```
 printf("%d%d",a[1],a[2]);
```

Will give you the integer value corresponding to 's'

See the program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)    
{
        int a[3] =  {3, 5, "s"};
        printf("%d%s",a[1],a[2]);
}
```

This will not compile as `"s"` is treated as a two element character array.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `'s'` you are dealing with ASCII values,

```
 int a[3]={3,5,'s'};
```

in above case ACII value of `'s'` will be inserted into array which is `115`.

```
printf("%d%c",a[1],a[2]);
```

With `%c` you are printing char equivalent of ASCII `115`.

Comment: There are more character sets than just ASCII.

Comment: @thebusybee Well atleast in OP's case. I'm not here to cover whole set of character.

Comment: We don't know which character set the OP is using. I hope that these days everybody is aware of UTF and does **not** limit the programs to ASCII. Additionally, we didn't talk about the difference between _source character set_ and _execution character set_. Actually I'm using a C compiler the uses ASCII for the source and another character set for execution. In the latter set the characters (only upper case) follow the numerals directly, so that `'A' == '9' + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring an integer array which can hold 3 integers,  First two has no problem , but you are confused with the third one 's' , because it is of type char

In C char size is 1 byte and integer side is 2/4 bytes (depends on architecture)

And in C ASCII is used to represent character, and ASCII is nothing but some integer number that are agreed upon to map same character , e.g small 's' is number 115, so when you are storing 's' it is storing 115 which is an integer,

As an experiment, store 97 as an integer and use %c  in printf and see the output

Comment: "_because it is of type char_" No. `'s'` is of type `int`. You can verify this by using `sizeof('s')` which will output the same value as `sizeof(int)`

Comment: Note that C is not tied to ASCII, though ASCII is often (usually; predominantly) the code set used.